# Caching server for Android or some thing similar

Tags: android, google-play

Our Android app will be used in a place without internet. We have one server with limited internet there.

1. Can user download the app from the server instead of google play, the way we can use ios cache server?
2. If we keep a copy of app in the server and install from it, how can we update the app with latest version?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont know why this question got negative response. I also want to know if there is mac server like caching feature in Android or playstore. It's very useful for reduce internet usage for downloading same application or data from official server.

Of course, I talk about this one:
http://www.macworld.com/article/2918973/save-your-bandwidth-by-using-a-caching-server.html

Answer (score 0):

You can host the apk file on the server and download it to the devices for installation. However, you first need to enable third party source installation for the devices.

Link how to here,
https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-enable-third-party-app-installation-on-most-android-phones/

In terms of the update, you can always update the apk file anytime but you might need a separate system to notify the users/devices about the update. Probably by using SMS.